# .NET Core 6, Entity Framework Core, Oracle : an exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am using .NET Core 6 and Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore ( 7.21.11 )

--EDIT Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0

this is my setup

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContextOracle>(options =>
{
    options.UseOracle(builder.Configuration.
        GetConnectionString("OracleDatabase"), b => b.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11"))
        .LogTo(s => Debug.WriteLine(s))
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .EnableDetailedErrors();
});
```

the SQL generated from EF Core is:

```
DECLARE
l_sql     varchar2(32767);
l_cur     pls_integer;
l_execute pls_integer;

BEGIN
l_cur := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
l_sql := 'SELECT "h"."a", "h"."b", "h"."c"
FROM "schema"."sometable" "h"
FETCH FIRST :p_0 ROWS ONLY';
dbms_sql.parse(l_cur, l_sql, dbms_sql.native);
dbms_sql.bind_variable(l_cur, ':p_0', 10);
l_execute:= dbms_sql.execute(l_cur);
dbms_sql.return_result(l_cur);
END;
```

I am getting an error

> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query.

When I copy paste the raw SQL into Oracle SQL Developer, I get this error:

> PLS-00302: component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Since the query is generated by EF Core, I wonder where to move from here.

Comment: Implicit result sets appear to be a new feature in Oracle 12cR1 (according to https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1). Are you using Oracle 11g or older, by any chance?

Comment: sounds that your oracle component and DB don't match. For oracle this is important to use a matching component,

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production